# Hibernate get Data form one Table which is part of a Join in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, join, spring-data-jpa

I have a question. I have two Tables in Database and two Classes for Hibernate.

Class Artikel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Artikel")
public class Artikel{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String artikelbezeichnung;
    private int artikelnummer;
    private Float preis;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "artikel", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Artikeldetails> artikeldetails;
```

Class Artikeldetails

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ARTIKELDETAILS")
public class Artikeldetails {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String artikeldetail;
    private String artikelcustom;
    private String artikelselektion;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="artikelid")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Artikel artikel;
```

The JPA Query:

```
List<Artikel> findByArtikelnummer(@Param("artikelnummer") int artikelnummer);
```

The result is for example:

```
[{
        "id": 3,
        "artikelbezeichnung": null,
        "artikelnummer": 123,
        "preis": 123.0,
        "artikeldetails": [{
                "id": 4,
                "artikeldetail": "DetailNummer 1",
                "artikelcustom": "Detail Nummer 1",
                "artikelselektion": "Detail Nummer 1"
            }, {
                "id": 5,
                "artikeldetail": "DetailNummer 2",
                "artikelcustom": "Detail Nummer 2",
                "artikelselektion": "Detail Nummer 2"
            }, {
                "id": 6,
                "artikeldetail": "DetailNummer 3",
                "artikelcustom": "DetailNummer 3",
                "artikelselektion": "DetailNummer 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

That's fine and working but now I only want to get ONLY the Artikel Data without Join. How should I do that? Must I create a new Class for that?

I trying also to change this line:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM Artikel a where a.artikelnummer = :artikelnummer")
List<Artikel> findByArtikelnummer(@Param("artikelnummer") int artikelnummer);
```

but this is not working.

Comment: In what way is it not working? What error do you get?

Comment: I want a JSON only with the data from Artikel Class. Without the Join to Artikeldetails

Comment: Have you tried the `JsonIgnore` annotation above the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now the Solution:

if you include fetch = FetchType.LAZY to OneToMany and to ManyToOne so you can catch only one Entity with

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM Artikel a where a.artikelnummer = :artikelnummer")
List<Artikel> findByArtikelnummer(@Param("artikelnummer") int artikelnummer);
```

If You choose FetchType.Eager he will automaticaly Join every time the OneToMay relation.